# calling a function within a text tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I think I am getting something wrong, I keep getting an error of 'this.deliveryFareEstimate() is undefined'

I am trying to sum up values gotten from a prop, but its not working as planned, and I think maybe doing it wrong tho. I am roughly new to programming generally.
Below is a sample code I am using to achieve it.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {  View,  Text,  StyleSheet,  Image,  TouchableOpacity, SafeAreaView, StatusBar } from "react-native";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import RNSlidingButton, { SlideDirection } from "../../components/RNSlidingButton";
import { Block } from "../../components";

const PerKm = 55;
const PerKg = 35;

export default class ConfirmBooking extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    const { handleBackPress, estimatedWeight, deliveryDuration } = this.props;

    FareEstimate = () => {
      const totalDistanceCost = PerKm * deliveryDuration;
      const totalParcelWeight = PerKg * estimatedWeight;
      const estimatedFare = totalParcelWeight + totalDistanceCost;
      return estimatedFare;
    };

    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {/* Delivery Details */}
          <View style={styles.header}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={handleBackPress}
              style={styles.navBarButton}
            >
              <Ionicons name="md-arrow-back" size={23} color="#FFF" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={styles.headerText}> Details</Text>
          </View>
          {/* content holder */}
          <View style={styles.content}>
            <Block style={styles.generalBlock}>
              <Text style={styles.generalBlockHeaderText}>
                ETA from Pick up
              </Text>
              <Text style={styles.generalBlockText}>
                {deliveryDuration} Mins
              </Text>
            </Block>

            <Block style={styles.generalBlock}>
              <Text style={styles.generalBlockHeaderText}>
                Estimated Parcel Weight
              </Text>
              <Text style={styles.generalBlockText}>{estimatedWeight} Kg</Text>
            </Block>

            <View style={styles.fareAndConfirm}>
              <Text style={styles.fareAndConfirmHeaderText}>Fare</Text>
              <Text style={styles.fareAndConfirmText}>
                ${this.FareEstimate()}
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i dont see `'this.deliveryFareEstimate()` anywhere do you mean  `FareEstimate` ?

Comment: The function `deliveryFareEstimate` is another function? Where is it called?

Comment: no its not another function, I am calling it to return the total fare estimate in a text tag

Answer (score 4):

`FareEstimate` is not properly defined. Always use `const` or `let` to define a local variable.

```
    const FareEstimate = () => {
      const totalDistanceCost = PerKm * deliveryDuration;
      const totalParcelWeight = PerKg * estimatedWeight;
      const estimatedFare = totalParcelWeight + totalDistanceCost;
      return estimatedFare;
    };
```

Since FareEstimate is defined locally inside `render()`, Call it without `this`

```
<Text style={styles.fareAndConfirmText}>${FareEstimate()}</Text>
```

Comment: I think it's also missing a `const` or `let`

Comment: oh yeah, how did it even get this far.

Comment: I have tried calling it without this before and it wasnt working

Comment: yes because it's not defined with `const` or `let` it ends up in the global scope. I've edited the answer.